# Using perl script find file count with multiple pattern

Tags: perl

I want to search files count inside a directory.

If number of files in folder less than or equal to 5 list the file names with count,
else files not found in directory like "zero files found".

Ex: Files inside directory like

```
testfile1d_01012022.txt
testfile2d_01012022.txt
testfile4d_01012022.txt
testfile9d_01012022.txt
testfile7d_01012022.txt
```

based on above file names, I given search pattern

```
$Filename = "testfile*d*".
```

But final result getting like below

```
testfiled_01012022.txt
testfiled_01012022.txt
testfiled_01012022.txt
testfiled_01012022.txt
testfiled_01012022.txt  -its removed number after google d
```

below variables used in script.

```
my @files = grep!/^\.\.?$/, readdir DIR
$Filename =~ s/\*//g;
```

Let me know how to show available files with count.

Comment: That code will not search for those file names, as described in your pattern. Your code is incomplete. Please post a complete code sample with code that produces the output described.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are using this "search pattern".

```
$Filename = "testfile*d*"
```

What that looks like is a shell filename pattern, like if you were to say `ls testfile*d*` in the shell.  That's not how regular expressions work.

If you want a pattern that matches "testfile" and then some arbitrary string and then "d" and then some other arbitrary string, you would write that as

```
testfile.*d.*
```

Second, you're not using that pattern correctly.  Your code shows:

```
my @files = grep!/^\.\.?$/, readdir DIR
$Filename =~ s/\*//g;
```

The first line does read a list of files, but the second line doesn't do anything useful.  What you want your second line to be is:

```
my @matched_files = grep /testfile.*d.*/, @files;
```

When you do that, @matched_files will have all the files that match that regular expression.

HOWEVER, you don't have to use regular expressions at all to get a list of files. You can use the built-in `glob` function that DOES handle shell globbing like you want, and you don't need that `readdir` stuff.

```
my @files = glob( 'testfile*d*' ); # Note it uses shell glob syntax, not regex
```